# Improving a workflow for importing BibTeX citations

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I am hoping to draw upon the expertise of other LaTeX/BibTeX user to help improve a common workflow of mine.

Currently, I download and import BibTex citations from the likes of IEEE/Springer/ScienceDirect and then cut and paste the citation into JabRef.  That is, it goes something like this:

- (In firefox) IEEE/Springer/Whatever -> Export as BibTeX
- Open `export.bib` in gedit
- Create new article in JabRef
- Copy-paste citation text from gedit into Jabref.

Trying to open the `export.bib` file into Jabref has it open the BibTeX file as a new database and I have to copy and paste the citation anyway.

I would like to improve this workflow to a one-click "Open With" when I save the `.bib` from Firefox and it gets added to my BibTeX database.

I currently use JabRef, but would be willing to switch BibTeX managers if something else (in Linux) offers this feature.  Of course, a script with `cat $FILE >> /path/to/my_database.bib` might work, but I then still have to find that reference to link it to the paper I just saved :)

Comment: JabRef can import files into a bib-file: File --> Import into current database.

Comment: You might also consider using a different tool, e.g. [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) or [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/features/) both have a "one-click savo-to-database button" for all major browsers, including Firefox. Web-based alternatives are [Connotea](http://www.connotea.org/), [citeulike](http://www.citeulike.org/) or [BibSonomy](http://www.bibsonomy.org/). All of the mentioned programs allow export to `.bib` files which can be used directly or manipulated using [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You might also consider switching to `biblatex+biber` as `biber` can open remote .bib data sources directly with no importing or downloading at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set up Jabref to automatically import a reference from Firefox into the current database, but it's somewhat arcane. Here is my solution under Linux:

1) Select Options -> Preferences -> Advanced -- and check "Listen for remote operation ..." I don't think it matters which port.

2) Create a small bash script (text file) named "jabref-import" that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar ~/local/jabref/JabRef-2.8.1.jar -i --importToOpen "$*"
```

Replace "~/local/jabref/JabRef-2.8.1.jar" with the path to your Jabref .jar file on your machine. Or if you have a working executable called "jabref", you can replace everything before the "-i" with "jabref". Just make sure your executable accepts command-line options (mine didn't).

In Ubuntu 13.04, the following variant of the script works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
jabref -i --importToOpen "$*"
```

3) Make the file executable:

```
chmod ugo+x jabref-import
```

4) Make sure Jabref is already open. Go to Firefox, download a citation file. It could be a .bib or .ris or .ref or whatever. Select the "Open with..." option in the dialog, and select the jabref-import executable that you just made. The import dialog should pop up in Jabref with your citation.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution about 6 months after I first asked :)   It is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: For WIndows Batch this translates to `"C:\Program Files\JabRef\JabRef.exe" --importToOpen "%1"`

Comment: Also check out **JabFox** below; it is cleaner than this solution, though this one remains as the accepted answer for historical reasons.

Answer (score 18):

If you have the BibTeX-Code available and copy that to your clipboard (either by opening the `export.bib` or by copying it from the homepage) and you click on the JabRef window (so that it has the focus) you can just paste (Ctrl+V) it as a new entry.

I knew that from BibDesk (Mac OS) which I am using and found the same for JabRef here http://sourceforge.net/projects/jabref/forums/forum/318825/topic/1653744

Comment: Quite helpful. Reduces the workflow by a step or two. To find the article quickly again, sort by timestamp.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Extremely useful.

Comment: i think this is still the best answer in 2021 but you need to use *BibItNow* on Firefox or a similar extension for easy access to the bibtex code. Otherwise, there's 3 or 4 additional steps in there and this becomes impractical.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my workflow.

1. Get the DOI of the article to cite. You find the DOI on the download page of the paper and it is also usually printed on the first page of the paper.
2. Paste the DOI into the Jabref search plugin `DOI to BibTeX` and press "fetch".
3. You will get a "list" of the search results, which is in most cases only one item. Click "OK" to import them.
4. Check the new entry in your bib file.

The benefit is that you need less time to import a new article. The DOI is also often easier to spot then the `Export` button on the web page.

Comment: I realized that using DOI import does not return the correct entry type. For example, I had a lot of Inproceeding entries that were recognized as articles by DOI import. Do you encounter similar issues?

Comment: @tc88, most if not all proceeding articles, which I have cited, were published in a citable journal, so I did not bother to change the bib entry type from `@ARTICLE` to `@INPROCEEDING`.

Answer (score 3):

I typically create a BibTeX file with very basic information, e.g., just the title,

```
@article{ocv,
  title={The optimal centroidal Voronoi tessellations and the gersho's conjecture in the three-dimensional space},
}
```

and then run [betterbib](https://github.com/nschloe/betterbib) on it:

```
betterbib my.bib out.bib
```

```
%comment{This file was created with BetterBib v2.1.0.}

@article{ocv,
  author = {Du, Qiang and Wang, Desheng},
  publisher = {Elsevier BV},
  doi = {10.1016/j.camwa.2004.12.008},
  title = {The optimal centroidal Voronoi tessellations and the gersho's conjecture in the three-dimensional space},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2004.12.008},
  journal = {Computers & Mathematics with Applications},
  number = {9-10},
  month = may,
  volume = {49},
  source = {CrossRef},
  year = {2005},
  pages = {1355-1373}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Today there is a AddOn for Firefox called **JabFox**. It uses functionality of Zotero (which should be installed) to 1-click-import things into JabRef. Works fine.

Comment: Aside from some minor formatting issues with the import, this works really well.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a variation to Damien's for KDE (4.14):

1) the same - check "Listen for remote operation ..."

2) Go to the KDE `System settings > File Assosiations`.

3) Create new file type (button "+ Add..." in the bottom):

- group - `text`
- type name - `bibliography`

4) Select `bibliography` and in the right part of window "Add...":

- Filename Patterns: `*.ris`, `*.bib`, `*.ref`, `*.enw` and so on.
- Application Preference Order: `Education > Science > JabRef`
  (or write here command like `/usr/local/bin/jabref %f` - this is for
  PC-BSD)

5) Apply.

Now you can click on file in browser and select "Open..." - import window will arise (you should start JabRef firstly!).