# Improving JabRef workflow under windows

Tags: import, jabref

I actually want to achieve exactly this: [Improving a workflow for importing BibTeX citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79251/improving-a-workflow-for-importing-bibtex-citations), but with windows.

And I am not sure how to make it work with the explanantion given, can anybody help or give a little bit more detailed answer?

Comment: I am not sure where your problems are, but why don't you use the functionality of the JabRef internal searches? (Springer, IEEEXplore, Google scholar etc) together with the JabFox addon?
And if you asscociate the .bib file extension in your system with JabRef, it will default open all bib files. In Firefox, if you choose run instead of download, the bib file will be directly imported in JabRef on a new tab. Then you can simply copy & paste that entry